# Is there any updated version of magmi for magento 2?

Tags: php, magento2, magmi

I am working on a project which is developed in Magento 2. I want to import products from another source. is there an updated version available for Magento 2?

Or is there any other free tool to import products and customers

Answer (score 0):

I am using

- For products: https://github.com/bigbridge-nl/product-import
- For customers: the Magento 2 API

By the way, your Magento 2 questions are better suited here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/